# Node keeps crashing due to: `ValueError: generator already executing`

Tags: ros, ros-humble

One ROS node I implemented keeps crashing with the error `ValueError: generator already executing`. I have no clue what is going on, this node doesn't have anything special. I run it with a launchfile, the other nodes I implemented keep running, but this one keeps crashing. Any ideas on what the problem might be? Any help is appreciated!

Here is the code of my node:

- [configuration_planner_node.py](https://github.com/kas-lab/rosa/blob/main/rosa_plan/rosa_plan/configuration_planner_node.py)
- [configuration_planner.py](https://github.com/kas-lab/rosa/blob/main/rosa_plan/rosa_plan/configuration_planner.py)

Here is the full error message:

```
[configuration_planner_node.py-2] Traceback (most recent call last):
[configuration_planner_node.py-2]   File "/home/gus/exp_metacontrol_ws/install/rosa_plan/lib/rosa_plan/configuration_planner_node.py", line 40, in <module>
[configuration_planner_node.py-2]     main()
[configuration_planner_node.py-2]   File "/home/gus/exp_metacontrol_ws/install/rosa_plan/lib/rosa_plan/configuration_planner_node.py", line 28, in main
[configuration_planner_node.py-2]     executor.spin()
[configuration_planner_node.py-2]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 279, in spin
[configuration_planner_node.py-2]     self.spin_once()
[configuration_planner_node.py-2]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 764, in spin_once
[configuration_planner_node.py-2]     self._spin_once_impl(timeout_sec)
[configuration_planner_node.py-2]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 745, in _spin_once_impl
[configuration_planner_node.py-2]     handler, entity, node = self.wait_for_ready_callbacks(
[configuration_planner_node.py-2]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 691, in wait_for_ready_callbacks
[configuration_planner_node.py-2]     return next(self._cb_iter)
[configuration_planner_node.py-2] ValueError: generator already executing
```

This is how I spin the node:

```
import rclpy

from rclpy.executors import MultiThreadedExecutor
from rosa_plan.configuration_planner import ConfigurationPlanner


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    try:
        executor = MultiThreadedExecutor()
        lc_node = ConfigurationPlanner('configuration_planner')
        executor.add_node(lc_node)
        try:
            executor.spin()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, rclpy.executors.ExternalShutdownException):
            executor.shutdown()
            lc_node.destroy_node()
        finally:
            executor.shutdown()
            lc_node.destroy_node()
    finally:
        rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have ubuntu 22.04 and I am running ROS 2 humble

Answer (score 0):

I updated the ubuntu packages and this was solved.

```
apt update && apt upgrade
```

Comment: From what version to what version?

Comment: I wrote wrong, I didn't upgrade ubuntu, I just updated its packages with `apt update && apt upgrade`. I have ubuntu 22.04, and I am running ROS 2 humble. I edited the awnser accordingly.